# Time complexity while loop with recursion

Tags: performance, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

```
   void call(int n)
    {
         for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
         {
           call(n/2);
          }
     }

   void main()
    {
      int i;
      for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
          call(i);
       }
     }
```

For the time complexity of this loop. Is this thought process correct? In the main function, the loop is O(N). In the call function, the loop is O(N), which the recursion is n/2, therefore the O(logN)with base 2. So the overall time complexity of in the main is O(N)*[O(N)*O(LogN)]= O(N^2 Log N)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: i am just having trouble with the recurison of (n/2) i am not sure if O(Log N) is correct

Comment: Hi tyc72. Welcome on stackoverflow. can you provide more details to your question. I recommend you also to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to find the big o estimate for this given code. My question is whether O(n^2 log N) is correct for this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use recursion tree to figure out the number of calls and the order of recursion function is equal to the number of nodes in the recursion tree (leaves are call(n/2) that is not showing):

[image]
so to calculate the number of all nodes you can calculate summation and estimate the order (using geometric sequence by formula to calculate summation) :

[image]

Order of the main loop is less than [image], so main loop order is [image]

Comment: Wouldnt the call function be O(n* log n)?

Comment: I calculated the call function order not the main loop, it is o(n^lgn)

Comment: I am just a bit confused as to why it is n^log n and not n*log n.

Comment: Rrecursive tree is showing all the calls, you need to find the number of calls that is same as number of nodes in tree to find out what order is.

Comment: so the main loop would be O(N^(Log N+1)?

Comment: You can calculate summation of first logn terms of a geometric sequence by formula.

Comment: Thank you! really helped me understand it!